# Prevent autoloading for abstract controller in symfony

Tags: symfony, sonata-admin

I have an abstract controller which has a function `getStatusAction` to render a status based on the entity which will come as parameter.

```
abstract class HumanController extends CRUDController
{
    public function getStatusAction(Human $human)
    {

     // return new Response ...
    }
}
```

Human is an entity class but also abstract. One child is for example man.

So i create a ManController

```
class ManController extends HumanController
{
}
```

If i now call in my twig template the getStatusAction with something like

```
{{ path('path_to_man_controller_status_action', {'human' : '12'}) }}
```

An error occurs, because some mechanism tries to guess that my parameter is a human which is an abstract class. But this cannot be instantiated.

> The provided class Human is abstract, and can not be instantiated

Instead i want that the mechanism should load the entity from my concrete class, in this case `Man`.

Yes, the framework can't know what class is meant, but how to solve this? I want to have one central function which is doing something with all my entities which are childs of the Human class. I don't want to write the getStatusAction function over and over again in my child classes.

So, is it at least possible to overwrite the abstract class function definition (with `getStatusAction(Man $man)`) but keep the implementation of the original class?

If not, is it possible to turn off the symfony automatic entity loading mechanism to pass just the entities trough my function?

Some other smart ideas? Thanks.

Comment: "I want to have one central function which is doing something with all my entities which are childs of the Human class" --- traits may be a very good place for these, don't you think?

Comment: I think the problem is that the entity loading mechanism is doing something like $em=>getRepository('Human')->find(12);  Since human is abstract it is not a doctrine entity.  You are using [mapped inheritance](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.6/reference/inheritance-mapping.html)?  If so then I suspect you need a [custom param converter](https://symfony.com/doc/master/bundles/SensioFrameworkExtraBundle/annotations/converters.html#creating-a-converter).  But I could be wrong.

Comment: Cerad is exactly right.

Comment: You all miss a simple but concrete problem: you cannot specialize the `Human` type in subcontroller as PHP won't let you do this kind of typing.

Comment: The custom param converter also gets as parameter the class Human ... how the param converter should know, what is meant?

Comment: @JimPanse That is indeed the question.  I messed around a bit with Doctrine inheritance but found it too limiting.  I think you will need to issue a sql query on the discriminator column to determine which type of concrete class is needed.  Then do a regular $em->find.  Seems like there should be an easier way but I never found one.  Never much cared for the param converter either.  Too much magic for my taste.

Comment: Yes, some requirements / special cases pushing php/ symfony to their limits ... :/

Comment: I'll go for the following solution: Write the getStatusAction method to each controller, but outsource the logic in there to the abstract ... i can't find and easier/cleaner way